# A programmer's favorite candy

Tags: riddle, humor

The bigger version of me is used to make marriages faster
At least, that's what they show on TV
I'm known to the U.S, young and old
Although programmers personally prefer me the most
In fact, I hear they have stacks of me!

**Hint**:

> The title matters!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> Push Pop

Reasoning:

> Push pop is a candy and programmers push and pop elements in stacks. I'm still thinking about marriage and young and old. There's been a jumbo push pop commercial on TV, where the jumbo push pop speeds the wedding up. Push pops were introduced by a U.S. company in the 80s and is still popular today.

Comment: You're close with popping from stacks! You're just missing one word...

Comment: As for your other clues, the "bigger" one doesn't seem to fit the clue I'm thinking about

Comment: It also doesn't have anything to do with music

Comment: Is it push pop?

Comment: *slow claps* You did it!

Comment: Yay! :) Now I need to think of how it fits in with marriage and the U.S. young and old.

Comment: I'll be waiting to give you that green check...

Answer (score -1):

Is the answer

> "Proposal"

?

It surely makes marriage faster.

Programmers have a lot of it through

> brain storming

but I don't have an idea if it is really known to the U.S

Comment: The title says it's a candy.. and I'm not sure if a proposal is a candy :)

Comment: Is it a candy that is known in U.S?

Comment: Yes, it is  a candy that is known in the U.S.

Answer (score -1):

It's

> register

... because

> a marriage register makes the process faster; US citizens are registered at birth, and; programmers manipulating the stack are writing and reading from CPU registers!